# For Expression in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am still new to terraform and trying to understand how For expression works.  I am trying to understand how we can select Key and Value in a map or object within the following example?

```
locals {
  projects = {
    customer_api = {
      region       = "australiasoutheast"
      environments = ["dev", "uat", "prd"]
    }
    partner_api = {
      region       = "australiasoutheast"
      environments = ["dev", "prd"]
    }
    internal_api = {
      region       = "australiaeast"
      environments = ["prd"]
    }
  }
}




locals {
  australiasoutheast_region = [
    for k, v in local.projects :
    k
    if v.region == "australiasoutheast" && contains(v.environments, "uat")
  ]
}
```

What is the Key and Value in above example and how can we decide it ?

Comment: What is the desired output? What do you want the new local to be?

Comment: we only want to return projects in australiasoutheast with a uat environment. I am following this article -  https://brendanthompson.com/posts/2022/10/terraform-for-expression . I want to know, how do we know which one are the key and value ?

Comment: Isn't that what your code already does? It returns `customer_api`

Comment: yes. this is what i got from the mentioned link.. i am trying to understand what is the k and v in above example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`for` expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for) has a few different clauses:

- `for k, v`: declares two temporary symbols `k` and `v` which will represent the current element's key and value in the subsequent clauses.
- `in local.projects`: declares the source collection that will be the input to this operation. Terraform will evaluate the remaining clauses once for each element in the given collection.
- `: k`: The colon delimits the information about the inputs from the information about the outputs. In this case the output expression is just `k`, referring directly to the temporary symbol `k` declared in the `for` clause, but any valid expression would be allowed here and it will be evaluated for each element of `local.projects` that matches the predicate in the next clause.
- `if v.region == "australiasoutheast" && contains(v.environments, "uat")`: This optional filtering predicate allows you to retain only a subset of the elements from `local.projects` when building the result. Terraform will evaluate this expression for each element of `local.projects` and include in the result only elements for which the expression returns `true`.

In your particular example then, the `local.projects` value is actually of an object type rather than a collection type, but Terraform supports object types in `for` expressions by treating them essentially as maps. Terraform will therefore visit each attribute and associated value of the object type, evaluating the `if` and result clauses once for each input attribute:

- `k = "customer_api"`

  `v = { region = "australiasoutheast", environments = ["dev", "uat", "prd"] }`

  `if` clause returns `true`,

  so add `k` to the result
- `k = "partner_api"`

  `v = { region = "australiasoutheast", environments = ["dev", "prd"] }`

  `if` clause returns `false` (`v.environments` does not contain `"uat"`)

  so skip this element
- `k = "internal_api"`

  `v = { region = "australiaeast", environments = ["prd"] }`

  `if` clause returns `false` (`v.region` is not `"australiasoutheast"`)

  so skip this element

After this process, only the first element's key was included, so the result is `["customer_api"]`.